# How to remove unwanted characters?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table , in one column data is 'su@re#sh$', now I want to output is 'suresh'? How to retrieve

Comment: Write a trigger which cleans up data at INSERT/UPDATE.

Comment: refer this- http://www.sqlrelease.com/allow-only-alphanumeric-characters-in-a-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [regexp_replace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm):

```
select regexp_replace('su@re#sh$', '[^0-9A-Za-z]', '') 
from dual
```

(you'll need to update this code for your table/column)

Comment: @user9293054, if you find this answer useful, don't forget to upvote and accept it!